# SvgIcon inheriting viewBox

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have different custom SVGs. Each one of this SVG has an own viewBox.

**First Svg**

```
<svg viewBox="-4 -4 24 24"><path something/></svg>
```

**Second Svg**

```
<svg viewBox="-5 -7 24 24"><path something/></svg>
```

**Third Svg**

```
<svg viewBox="-2 -1 24 24"><path something/></svg>
```

And so on...

I am using the Material UI component: `SvgIcon`.

```
<SvgIcon
  component={component} // This is my custom SVG
/>
```

The `SvgIcon` has a default view of `'0 0 24 24'` and it is what is "set" for every SVG. I want it to inherit from the `component`.

I know I can defined a property such as:

```
<SvgIcon
  component={component}
  viewBox="my values" // Example "0 0 20 20"
/>
```

but the `viewBox` varies across different SVGs

Comment: Can you redefine your custom svgs as a raw JS object with a string path and a string viewBox?  How are they defined now?

Comment: That is the way I did it, but ideally I want to use `< SvgIcon  />`. The reason behind it is because I am using a mix of custom SVGs and Material UI SVGs. Only the custom one have the `viewBox` issue

Answer (score 1):

One solution I've found is to provide the same matching viewBox from your original svg file to MUI's `SvgIcon` component. Otherwise, MUI's SvgIcon will use their default of `0 0 24 24` (defined [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/svg-icon/#props)) which might not match the one from your svg.

Example:

The original svg might look like this, defining its own viewBox:

```
<svg width="12" height="12" viewBox="0 0 12 12">
    <path d="..."/>
</svg>
```

Use your custom svg file with MUI's `SvgIcon`:

```
import MyCustomIcon from '../assets/MyCustomIcon.svg';

// ...

<SvgIcon
  component={MyCustomIcon}
  viewBox="0 0 12 12"
/>
```

You can see that the viewBox used in the `SvgIcon` matches the one from the original svg file.

I hope this helps.